# Finding rows, where Name variates, but not the mail adress

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an problem as follows, burning my mind pretty hard.

Imagine the following table (the second_id is unimportant and saying that i should use unique() is not working in my case)

```
create table adressen (

id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
second_id int,
name char(64),
email char(64)
);

INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('1','max','max@test.com');
INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('1','peter','peter@test.com');
INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('1','emma','emma@test.com');
INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('2','max','max@test.com');
INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('2','peeter','peter@test.com');
INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('2','emma','emma@test.com');
INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('3','maax','max@test.com');
INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('3','elisa','elisa@test.com');
INSERT INTO adressen (second_id, name, email) VALUES ('3','eemmaa','emma@test.com');
```

As you can see, there are multiple users with the same mail, but with different names.
Im trying to select all mails, where multiple names exist.

In this case it would be:

- `emma@test.com` with the two different names (`emma`, `eemmaa`)
- `max@test.com` with the two  different names (`max`, `maax`)
- `peter@test.com` with the two  different names (`peter`, `peeter`)

So the output shall be 1 row for each "set" of name and mail, like:

```
emma@test.com , emma
emma@test.com , eemmaa
max@test.com, max
max@test.com, maxx
petertest.com, peter
petertest.com, peeter
```

I don't want to get the rows where mail and name are the same. Also i dont want to get a row, if there is only one entry (in this case for karl) in my table

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: assuming the table name is `users`: `SELECT mail,name FROM users WHERE mail IN (SELECT mail FROM users GROUP BY mail HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1)`

Comment: You don't have any rows in your example with email and name the same. If you mean that the name is the same as the local-part of the email address, please [edit] your question to specify that.

Comment: @O.Jones He means they're both the same as another row, like rows 7 and 8.

Comment: Should emma be in the result if id 9 was not there? ie do you want exact duplicates (who don't have multiple distinct names, but have multiple rows) to appear in your list?

Comment: @Bohemian No, emma should not appear, if ID 9 was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery that finds all the `mail` values with more than one different `name`, and join with the table itself.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.mail, a.name
    FROM tbl a
    JOIN (
              SELECT mail
                FROM tbl
               GROUP BY mail
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
         ) b ON a.mail = b.mail
   ORDER BY a.mail, a.name;
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/BCOP84426)

This is based on O. Jones's answer, but adds `COUNT(DISTINCT name)` so that rows that have the same name and email aren't counted as duplicates.

Comment: Now its working perfectly fine! Thanks for the correct answer, and the quick replys !

Answer (score 2):

First get a result set containing the duplicated email addresses.

```
              SELECT mail
                FROM tbl
               GROUP BY mail
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then use that as a virtual table and join it to your detail table

```
  SELECT a.mail, a.name
    FROM tbl a
    JOIN (
              SELECT mail
                FROM tbl
               GROUP BY mail
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
         ) b ON a.mail = b.mail
   ORDER BY a.mail, a.name
```

You might try deduplicating the result set like this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT a.mail, a.name
    FROM tbl a
    JOIN (
              SELECT mail
                FROM tbl
               GROUP BY mail
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
         ) b ON a.mail = b.mail
   ORDER BY a.mail, a.name
```

Comment: This is giving me a table, in which are all multiple mails, but there are still duplicates of rows, where email and name are the same.

Comment: Try `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1`, so it doesn't count rows where both email and name are the same.

Comment: @Barmar, in this case there is no output

Comment: @SebaM Can you make a sqlfiddle, or post the input data as plain text so we can copy and paste it?

Comment: @Barmar Sure thing, but how can i upload it or post it. Its too long for a comment, sorry never used sqlfiddle.

Comment: add distinct to the select and also add distinct to the having clause as @Barmar advised.

Comment: @SebaM Paste it into the question then mark it as code with Ctl-k or the `{}` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct mail,name FROM table 
      WHERE mail IN (SELECT mail FROM table GROUP BY mail HAVING COUNT(distinct name) > 1)
  order by mail,name;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not what im looking for. It is not about the part before the @ compared to the name.

Comment: Then what do you mean by : "I don't want to get the rows where mail and name are the same."

Comment: He means they're both the same as another row.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was pretty unclear. I meant, if there are 2 rows where the names of the rows, and the mails of the rows are the same. So if i have in row 1 name AAA and mail 1234@1234.de and in row 2 name AAA and mail 1234@1234.de as well, just want it to get a single time.

Comment: IDs 7 and 8 are an example.

Comment: You need `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1`, so it doesn't count rows  with the same name and email as duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar I think my query will work if I just put distinct before name while selecting the data.

Comment: @Harshil No, because the de-duplication has to be done when checking whether the email has duplicate names to begin with.

Comment: You can't put `DISTINCT` in the middle of a select list like that. `DISTINCT` applies to the entire select list, not individual columns.

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer. That'll be helpful to the future visitors.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by O Jones answer and comments

This should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.mail, a.name
FROM tbl a
JOIN (
          SELECT mail
            FROM tbl
           GROUP BY mail
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
     ) b ON a.mail = b.mail
ORDER BY a.mail, a.name
```